# Rx - start buffering onNext

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive-programming

Using [`Observable.Buffer(TimeSpan timeSpan) Method`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.linq.observable.buffer(v=vs.103).aspx), which splits stream into 10 minute chunks and returns as `IList`, that works fine

```
var stream = Observable.FromEventPattern<*>(*,*);
stream.Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
```

Trying to implement more complex behavior

- Start chunk (buffered events list) when **new event is pushed into stream** *(instead of every 10 second)*
- Continue buffering events until **no event is pushed into stream for `x` seconds**

Comment: No sure what is the question here

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var query =
    stream.Publish(
        ps => ps.Window(
            () => ps.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0)).Take(1)));
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there are a quite a few ways you could do this.

I have a working tested example here

```
void Main()
{
    var scheduler = new TestScheduler();
    var stream = scheduler.CreateColdObservable(
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(1.Seconds(), 'A'),
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(2.Seconds(), 'B'),
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(13.Seconds(), 'C')
        );

    var observer = scheduler.CreateObserver<string>();

    var query = stream.Publish(s => {
        return s.Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), Observable.Empty<char>(), scheduler)
            .ToList()
            .Where(buffer=>buffer.Any())    
            //Project to string to make equality test easier for the example.       
            .Select(buffer=>string.Join(",", buffer))
            .Repeat();
    });

    query.Subscribe(observer);

    scheduler.AdvanceBy(100.Seconds());

    ReactiveAssert.AreElementsEqual(
        new []{
            ReactiveTest.OnNext(12.Seconds(), "A,B"),
            ReactiveTest.OnNext(23.Seconds(), "C")
        },
        observer.Messages);
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public static class TimeEx
{
    public static long Seconds(this int seconds)
    {
        return TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds).Ticks;
    }
}
```

Note here that I just make the Buffered list a string to make it easier to validate the equality. i.e. `"A,B"` instead of `{'A', 'B'}`

Other options to consider are the `Window` or `GroupJoin` operators to do this - see http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/17_SequencesOfCoincidence.html. And other operators I am sure can be stitched together like `Switch`, `Select`, `Timer`, `Timeout` etc to get your result.